# kable_input not found when knitting using knitr and knitExtra

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm brand new at R and I would like to make a neat table of my dataset using the packages kable and knitExtra in Rmarkdown. I'll try to explain the error through my code:

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
library(readxl); library(dplyr); library(kableExtra); library(knitr)
Froot <- read_excel("~/Documents/Project1/Fruit.xlsx")

knitr::kable(Froot[1:4])
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"))
````

In the above code, when I try to knit it returns this error:

> Quitting from lines 37-39 (Project1.Rmd)
>
> Error in kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed")) : 
>   argument "kable_input" is missing, with no default
>
> Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> kable_styling
>
> Execution halted

I notice the error is in the function "kable_styling", and so I attempted to solve the issue by just adding "kable_input", which turns the code into this:

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
library(readxl); library(dplyr); library(kableExtra); library(knitr)
Froot <- read_excel("~/Documents/Project1/Fruit.xlsx")

knitr::kable(Froot[1:4])
  kable_styling(kable_input, bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"))
````

But when I knit, it tells me that function "kable_input" could not be found!!

> Quitting from lines 37-39 (Project1.Rmd)
>
> Error in kable_input() : could not find function "kable_input"
>
> Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> kable_styling
>
> Execution halted

Any fixes? I've tried googling it but I literally got no results.

Comment: Seems there is a missing pipe-operator in your code. Try `knitr::kable(Froot[1:4]) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"))`.

Comment: @stefan I added the pipe-operator into my code, yet it still yields the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@stefan is right, yout have to add the pipe %>% and also remove kable_input which he did in his comment. Also, you can remove include=FALSE from the chuck (this evaluates the code but doesn't show the result).

````
```{r}
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)

Froot <- read_excel("~/Documents/Project1/Fruit.xlsx")


knitr::kable(Froot)%>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"))
```
````

This example works in my case:

```
knitr::kable(iris)%>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"))
```